# How to extend Dell Laptop Latitude E6410 screen to 2 external LCD monitors using a dock with 2 DVI ports?

Tags: dell-latitude, extended-desktop

I'm running Windows 7 enterprise.

Two of my external LCD monitors are connected to my Latitude E6410 through the 2 DVI ports on the dock. However, I could only get 2 screens to display at the same time. Either the laptop screen & 1 LCD monitor or just the 2 external LCD monitors. How do I make the 3 to display at the same time?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this EXACT machine (so I won't make this an answer), but this is a very common limitation of a lot of laptops.  It's by design.  The simplest workaround is a USB video adapter for the extra LCD.

Answer (score 1):

The GPU in the E6410 only supports up to two monitors at a time.

You should look at a USB video adapter if you need more than two screens.

Comment: Correct.  If you keep the laptop lid closed, the 2 external monitors will work.  If you open the lid, one will turn off